# Telerik RadDataPager, how to add pagesize field in pager

Tags: .net, wpf, telerik, radgridview, raddatapager

I am trying to implement raddatapager in my wpf application. Everything seems to be working fine except for the pagesize field. I can get the pagesize field in my page. It's showing other stuff like total pages, next previous button but not the pagesize field. i want to give an option to the user to change the pagesize from pager.
I find something like this https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/paging/pagingwithraddatapager/defaultcs.aspx but in wpf application.

Here is my code:

```
  <telerik:RadDataPager x:Name="radDataPager" 
           Source="{Binding DataList}" 
           Grid.Row="3" 
           Grid.Column="1"
           DisplayMode="All"                           
           PageSize="20" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no built-in UI for this tasks, but it should be achievable with slight modification of the template. I tried this and it seems to be working fine.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadDataPager}">
                    <Grid>
                        <DataPager:DataPagerPresenter AutoEllipsisMode="{TemplateBinding AutoEllipsisMode}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" DisplayMode="{TemplateBinding DisplayMode}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" ItemCount="{Binding ItemCount, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" NumericButtonStyle="{TemplateBinding NumericButtonStyle}" NumericButtonCount="{TemplateBinding NumericButtonCount}" PageCount="{TemplateBinding PageCount}" PageSize="{Binding PageSize, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PageIndex="{TemplateBinding PageIndex}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 120 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <TextBlock Text="Page Size:" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBox Height="20" Width="20"
                            Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=PageSize}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Slight placement modifications might be needed to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in UI for the PageSize. However, there is a [runnable project](https://github.com/telerik/xaml-sdk/tree/master/DataPager/ChangePageSizeDynamically) and a [help article](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/raddatapager/how-to/change-page-size-dynamically) in the Telerik's resources that show how to achieve this. Basically, you can modify the default ControlTemplate of the DataPagerPresenter element.